# Tomcat not picking keystore from path

Tags: java, tomcat, keystore

I have a requirement to set javax.net.ssl.keyStore with a particular keystore file in my java code. Now the issue is if I run the code as an independent main function everything works fine. But when I deploy my code over tomcat then there is a SSL Handshake exception. I believe that keystore did not load properly when code is deployed over tomcat. Could anyone help in this regard?

The extension of my keystore file is .ks

Comment: Well, did you start Tomcat with the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` value defined?

Comment: @Andreas I have mentioned the keystore using the System.setProperty in my code flow. Will it not work that way?

Comment: Probably not, because by the time you call `System.setProperty`, the value has already been read. You need to give the value as a `-D` option when starting tomcat, *or* change your code to not rely on the property. You can usually give the keystore to use at the place where it is needed. The `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` property is just the default if you didn't specify otherwise.

Comment: @Andreas just now I added the property to tomcat as well. But it is still not working.

Comment: Did you try `System.getProperty` to see if you actually managed to set it correctly?

Comment: System.getProperty is returning the same value which has been set by me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132457/discussion-between-mohan-mishra-and-andreas).